# PIC, SPI problem with SD card and other devices

Tags: pic, spi, sd, enc28j60, expander

I'm using a [PIC24H](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70166a.pdf) as a master connected with a [microSD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size), ENC28J60 and a MCP28S08 port expander. I'm using the [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) library for a microSD card and the Microchip TCP/IP stack for ENC28J60.
All works fine, but I have some little problems that I can't explain...

The main problem is that the microSD card fails the initialization. To fix this problem I have to put a pull-up resistor (10k) on SDI (MISO) line. 
With it, the SD card works fine, and after initialization I can remove it and the card keeps to work, so I think the problem is really only during card initialization.

I can reset (MCLR) my PIC without a problem, but if I "power-on reset" (POR), it then I have to use the pull-up resistor.

Anyway, this creates another problem... If I use a pull-up resistor on the SDI line, then the MCP28S08 can't read the correct value of the GPIO port. To resolve this, I have to remove the resistor and then (without resetting the MCU too) starts to work good.

I noticed that when I remove the resistor and MCP starts to work, then I can add back the resistor without a problem because MCP keeps working... why? This make no sense...

My circuit is on a breadboard, maybe there are some interferences on my circuit?

Could it be a timing issue?

I think an oscilloscope can help me to find out this problem. Now I use a Saleae logic analyzer, but I can't find the problem with this, because it can tell me only when a signal is 1 or 0... Can a PicoScope 2104 USB oscilloscope help me with this?

Comment: A circuit diagram would be helpful here.. are all your voltages of the devices the same, and correct?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] pull-up resistor(10k) on SDI(MISO) line. With it SD card works good, and after initialization i can remove it and the card keeps to work, so i think the problem is really only during card initialization.

The SD card pins will operate in "open drain" mode after power-on. They need a pullup to output "high" until you switch the card to SPI mode.

> Anyway, this create another problem... if i use a pull-up resistor on SDI line, then the MCP28S08 can't read the correctly value of GPIO port.

A 10k resistor will draw only 0.33 mA at 3.3 V. SPI outputs should be a *lot* stronger than that. You could try a bigger resistor, around 47 kOhm for a start, but you might need to lower the initialization frequency for your SD card.

Comment: I think you're right. I've never played with SD card.
My first guess was some cross talk interference. I think I may wrong.

Comment: Hi, thank you. So, what can be the problem if my SPI is not so "strong"? How can i check is SPI level is voltage is ok?